# How can I capture a data from the user while he/she is currently typing?

Tags: javascript, java, linked-list, stack, undo-redo

I am creating a program that will be using stack as a data structure. The program's main function is "redo" and "undo". The user will be typing anything on a GUI and there will be two buttons, redo and undo. I wanted to store each word on a particular node so whenever the user will be pressing the undo, the previous state of the text box will be applied.

So the problem is, how can I capture a data whenever the user will stop typing? Like should I get a timer then what? or should I just create a condition wherein I will store each word on a node?

Comment: Why did you use the Javascript _and_ the Java tags? What technology will you write your UI in? And what exactly is the question, how to detect when the user stopped typing?

Comment: "Java is to JavaScript as Ham is to Hamster". Java and JavaScript are two completely different things. Figure out which one you are using and [add some code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, [go through the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple debounce using a setTimeout so that you only record the state after x milliseconds of no typing. The state can just be stored in an array. pop() items off of it for your undo.

**Here's a *simple* proof of concept.** I'm not proud of it but it should be enough to get you started. Note that I've used jQuery for convenience but its fairly simple to do the same in vanilla JS.

```js
$(function() {

  var debounce = null, //ref for debouncer timeout     
      $textarea = $("#myTextarea"),
      $undo = $("#undo"),
      $undocount = $("#undo span"),
      history = [];

  $textarea.on("keyup", function() {
      clearTimeout(debounce); //clear the debounce
      debounce = setTimeout(function() {
        history.push($textarea.val());
        $undocount.text(history.length);
      }, 300);
  }).on("blur", function() {
      history.pop();
  });

  $undo.on("click", function() {
    $undocount.text(history.length);
    $textarea.val(history.pop());
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea>
<button id="undo">UNDO [<span>0</span>]</button>
```